# Branch points of rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

Let $f$ be a rational function on a compact connected Riemann surface $X$.  The rational function $f$ induces a holomorphic map $\overline{f}:X\to \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{C})$.

Let $x$ be a point on the Riemann sphere $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{C})$. How can I check that if $b$ is a branch point of $\overline{f}$ by looking at the derivative of $f$?

How does this work when $X=\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{C})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $b\in X$ and $f(b)\neq\infty$ then $b$ is a branch point iff $f'(b)=0$ (derivative wrt. an arbitrary local coordinate; the ramification index is the maximal $k$ s.t. $f^{(k)}(b)=0$ (the number of branches meeting at $b$ is $k+1$)). If $f(b)=\infty$, replace $f$ with $1/f$.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick on terminology: If $b$ is in $X$, one should call it a ramification point right? The branch locus being the image of the ramification locus.

Comment: @Harry: you are of course right

Comment: A little [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462252): $z=\infty$ is not branch point of $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+1}$, but $(\frac{1}{f})'(0)=0$

Comment: @Andrews $z$ is not a local coordinate around $z=\infty$. We can use $w=1/z$, so now $1/f =w/\sqrt{1+w^2}$. And indeed $\frac{d(1/f)}{dw}(0)\neq 0$. No problem here.

Comment: @user8268 Thanks for your time and kindly explanation, this contributes a lot to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255386/)

Comment: And sometimes, it'll be complicated to determine the remification index/branch number at $\infty$, like in these questions: [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387498), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50351)

Comment: Hi @Andrews, sorry I know it's been some time this post has been answered, but reading your comments I wonder how come that $\frac{1}{f}(w) = \frac{w}{\sqrt{1 + w^2}}$, and not just $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + w^2}}$ ?